# Trying to add and remove class based on the width of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I'm currently working on that listens to the width of the element and adds and removes a `class` on a specific breakpoint. When I try to use `$(window).on('resize', function()` to execute the script when resizing the browser it doesn't seem to be working.

Check the `console` for any errors but there doesn't seem to be any errors

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="content-area"></div>

    <div class="card-collection -grid">
        <div class="articles-view">
            <div class="article-card">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $contentAreaWrapper = $('.tab-content .content-area');

    if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() <= 660) {
        $('.card-collection').removeClass('-grid');
        $('.articles-view').addClass('-list-grid-aligned');
    }

    else if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() >= 660) {
        $('.card-collection').addClass('-grid');
        $('.articles-view').removeClass('-list-grid-aligned');
    }
})

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var $contentAreaWrapper = $('.tab-content .content-area');

    if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() <= 660) {
        $('.card-collection').removeClass('-grid');
        $('.articles-view').addClass('-list-grid-aligned');
    }

    else if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() >= 660) {
        $('.card-collection').addClass('-grid');
        $('.articles-view').removeClass('-list-grid-aligned');
    }
});
```

Comment: Add your HTML Code

Comment: Now which one did you actual use, `$(window).resize('on'` as you say in the text (and which would make no sense), or `$(window).on('resize'` as shown in the code? What have you done so far to debug this? Have you at least added a console.log statement to verify if this event handler fires?

Comment: are your classes really named `-grid` and `-list-grid-aligned` or do you want to add/remove classes **ending** in `-grid`/`-list-grid-aligned` ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Classes are actually named `-grid` and `-list-grid-aligned`

Comment: And how are you resizing to test the code?

Comment: Your code is OK, it should work.

Comment: You have code duplication in here, you can create a fonction which is called in the on callback and the ready callback

Comment: @clestcruz it should work. Do you have a live link where the problem can be seen ?

Answer (score 0):

Combining `offsetWidth` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth and the `resize` event should do the trick.

You listen for the `resize` event and when the width match your rule you're able act accordingly:

```
$(window).on('resize', () => {
  if ($(body).offsetWidth < 900) {
   $(body).addClass('lt-900');
    console.log('resized');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code working. Check the snippet in full page view

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $contentAreaWrapper = $('.tab-content .content-area');

   if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() <= 660) {
    $('.card-collection').removeClass('-grid');
    $('.articles-view').addClass('-list-grid-aligned');
   }

   else if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() >= 660) {
    $('.card-collection').addClass('-grid');
    $('.articles-view').removeClass('-list-grid-aligned');
   }
  })

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
   var $contentAreaWrapper = $('.tab-content .content-area');

   if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() <= 660) {
    $('.card-collection').removeClass('-grid');
    $('.articles-view').addClass('-list-grid-aligned');
   }

   else if ($contentAreaWrapper.width() >= 660) {
    $('.card-collection').addClass('-grid');
    $('.articles-view').removeClass('-list-grid-aligned');
   }
  });
```

```css
.-grid {
   color: red;
  }
  .-list-grid-aligned {
   color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="content-area"></div>

  <div class="card-collection -grid">
   <div class="articles-view">
    <h1>Articles View</h1>
    <div class="article-card">
     <h2>Article Card</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```